# How do PhD programs use information on where admitted and waitlisted students will be going?

Tags: graduate-admissions

I applied to several American PhD programs in statistics in the fall. A few days ago, I accepted an offer from one of them. I have since been emailing other programs that admitted me to decline their offer and programs that waitlisted me that I can be removed from their waitlist. Some programs have asked me where I'll be going. What do programs typically do with this information?

Comment: Put it in a folder and file it away, never to be looked at again? Well, they do look at it to try and figure out where they sit in the opinions of their applicants and what then think what they could do to get a higher number of acceptances in the future.

Comment: @JonCuster To do that, wouldn't they need the reasons why applicants decided to attend other programs? Only one of the programs that asked me where I'll be going also asked me why I decided to go there.

Comment: They have a general idea of what other programs are doing (support, RA vs TA, whatnot). So they are looking for general indicators of falling behind or catching up to other programs.